# how to display version only of curl

Tags: command-line

When `curl --version` is executed on the command line of a VM running Ubuntu 18.04 this is displayed in the terminal:

```
curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-01-24
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

How do I change the command so that only **7.58.0** is displayed?

Comment: Posting terminal information as images makes it difficult for responders to use part of the output in their answers or in requests for clarification. Instead, copy and paste the relevant output here using this site's [markdown formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little modification.

```
:~$ curl --version | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
7.58.0
```

`head -n 1` tells shell to print the first line of output.

`awk '{ print $2 }'` will print the second column.

---

You can also tell `awk` to print the second column of the first line, using `NR` built-in variable.

```
:~$ curl --version | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'
7.58.0
```

`NR==1` tells awk to print the first line of the output.

`{ print $2 }` will print the second column.

Comment: @JusticeforMonica Thanks, I was about to edit the post.

Comment: In the first part of the answer, the explanation of what each piece does is quite helpful.  Can an explanation be added to the second part to describe what `NR==1` does?

Comment: @knot22 Edited.